# No_Oauth_Token: Access token was not returned

Tags: oauth2, file-connect

Unable to access sharepoint via Files Connect.

1. A user with System Admin Permission created.
2. Enable Files COnnect in my org.
3. Created a permission set to access Files Connect Online and assigned to the above user.
4. Got Consumer Key and Consumer secret, and with them I created Auth Provider in Salesforce.
5. Set Authorize end point url and token end point url.
6. Created External Data Sources

I got my External  Data Sources - Authenticated as well.

But when I try to *"Validate & Sync"* it says *"OAuth token expired"*.

Please advise.

Comment: I tried to access all the links that has been generated while creating an entry in Auth. Providers. I am able to access, Test-Only Initialization URL, OAuth-Only Initialization URL but am unable to access Callback URL. I get the same error as mentioned above. This is a DEVELOPER Edition, is this the problem???

Comment: It wouldn't be because it's a DE. You should be able to access any org from a DE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While setting XML Permission in Sharepoint at appregnew.aspx

Change the Permission XML from "http://sharepoint/content/sitecollection/web" 
to 
"http://sharepoint/content/sitecollection"

This change had worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

See steps 6-8 in the steps to [setup Files Connect](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=admin_files_connect_perm.htm&language=en_US)

You still need to:

- Define an External Data Source for SharePoint
- Check **External Data Source Access** on the Permission Set
- Edit the Permission set and add specific data sources to the Enabled External Data Sources list

Comment: I have created External Data Source and checked in Permission Set and also added in the list. Still I have the same problem.